# Firebase on child added works even security rule denies the create object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I don't know how it is possible but even the security rules deny the new data it adds the new object on my view. I listen db as following:

```
dbRef = db.ref('/PostsCompany/' + companyKey + '/Posts').orderByChild('Date');
dbRef.on('child_added', function (snap) {
   console.log(snap.val());
})
```

db structure:

```
  {
    "PostsCompany" : {
      "-L3Y7zOHpKu0tbr-cyXQ" : {
        "LastPost" : {
          "CommentsEnabled" : true,
          "CompanyKey" : "-L3Y7zOHpKu0tbr-cyXQ",
          "Date" : 1517316150394,
          "Message" : "test msg",
          "PostKey" : "-L464lDsQc8wmpuynK_n",
          "Type" : "Post"
        },
        "Posts" : {
          "-L464lDsQc8wmpuynK_n" : {
            "CommentsEnabled" : true,
            "CompanyKey" : "-L3Y7zOHpKu0tbr-cyXQ",
            "Date" : 1517316150394,
            "Message" : "test msg",
            "Type" : "Post"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

related rule:

```
"PostsCompany": {
  "$companyKey": {
    ".read": "auth !== null",
    "Posts": {
        ".indexOn": ["Date"],
        "$postKey": {
            ".write": "auth.uid == root.child('CompanyPages')
                                       .child($companyKey)
                                       .child('OwnerUID')
                                       .val()",
            ".validate": "root.child('CompanyPages')
                              .child($companyKey)
                              .exists() &&
                          newData.hasChildren(['CompanyKey','Message','Date','Type','CommentsEnabled'])",
            "CompanyKey": {
                ".validate": "!data.exists() && 
                                        newData.val() == $companyKey"
            },
            "Date": {
                ".validate": "!data.exists() && 
                                        newData.val() <= now"
            },
            "Message": {
                ".validate": "!data.exists() && 
                                        newData.isString() && 
                                        newData.val().length<=1000"
            },
            "Type": {
                ".validate": "!data.exists() && 
                                        newData.val() == 'Post'"
            },
            "Media": {
                ".validate": "!data.exists() && 
                                        newData.hasChildren(['Type','Preview'])",
                "Type" : {
                    ".validate": "newData.val() == 'Image'"
                },
                "Preview" : {
                    ".validate": "newData.isString()"
                },
                "$other": {
                  ".validate": false
                }
            },
            "CommentsEnabled": {
                ".validate": "newData.isBoolean()"
            },
            "Comments": {
                ".read": " auth !== null",
                "$commentKey": {
                    ".write": " auth !== null &&
                                root.child('PostsCompany')
                                  .child($companyKey)
                                                .child('Posts')
                                  .child($postKey)
                                  .child('CommentsEnabled')
                                  .val() == true",
                    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['UID','Message','Date'])",
                    "UID": {
                        ".validate": "!data.exists() && 
                                      auth.uid == newData.val()"
                    },
                    "Date": {
                        ".validate": "!data.exists() && 
                                      newData.val() <= now"
                    },
                    "Message": {
                        ".validate": "!data.exists() && 
                                      newData.isString() && 
                                      newData.val().length<=1000"
                    },
                    "Likes": {
                        "$uidCommentLike": {
                            ".write": "auth.uid == $uidCommentLike",
                            ".validate": "newData.isBoolean()"
                        }
                    },
                    "Replies": {
                        "$replyKey": {
                            ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['UID','Message','Date'])",
                            "UID": {
                                ".validate": "!data.exists() && 
                                                            auth.uid == newData.val()"
                            },
                            "Date": {
                                ".validate": "!data.exists() && 
                                              newData.val() <= now"
                            },
                            "Message": {
                                ".validate": "!data.exists() && 
                                              newData.isString() && 
                                              newData.val().length<=1000"
                            },
                            "Likes": {
                                "$uidReplyLike": {
                                    ".write": "auth.uid == $uidReplyLike",
                                    ".validate": "newData.isBoolean()"
                                }
                            },
                            "$other": {
                              ".validate": false
                            }
                            }
                    },
                    "$other": {
                        ".validate": false
                    }
                }
            },
            "Likes": {
                "$uid": {
                    ".write": "auth.uid == $uid",
                    ".validate": "newData.isBoolean()"
                }
            },
            "$other": {
              ".validate": false
            }
        }
    }
  }      
},
```

When I try to add a new post, it displays an error as I expected 
(Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied).

But somehow dbRef still works and get the new data. I double check it on Firebase Console and it never adds the new data on db or nothing changes visually at least.

I guess validation control makes it which is newData.hasChildren() on my case. If one of the object is not sent (for example I tried without Type) and it occurs again.

```
newData.hasChildren(['CompanyKey','Message','Date','Type','CommentsEnabled'])
```

Comment: Please post your security rules and database structure... We might also need to see the value of `companyKey`

Comment: I edited the question and added full details

Comment: Both your code and your database structure show the node `CompanyPosts`. But your security rules don't have it. They have a `PostsCompany` node instead.

Comment: it was my mistake while writing here. corrected as "PostsCompany"

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is optimistic update performed by Firebase. It adds new post to local version of database before it's synced with Google's server vesion of database.

---

*Every client connected to a Firebase database maintains its own internal version of any active data. When data is written, it's written to this local version first. The Firebase client then synchronizes that data with the remote database servers and with other clients on a "best-effort" basis.*

See:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#write_data_offline

and

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/what-happens-to-database-listeners-when-security-rules-reject-an-update.html

---

`child_added` happens before rules are executed that's why it runs in your case and you can't see the result in Firebase Console at the same time.

If you define `child_removed`, you'll see that it's called straight after you create new post.